# How does Kafka Streams multithread/parallelize aggregation operations?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I tried a little experiment, and I'm wondering how to explain what I'm seeing.   The purpose
of the experiment was to try to understand how Kafka Streams is doing multithreading.  I 
created and populated an input Topic with three partitions.  Then I created a Streams graph
that included the following, and configured it to run with three threads.

```
kstream = kstream.mapValues(tsdb_object -> {
    System.out.println( "mapValues: Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    return tsdb_object;
});

// Add operator to print results to stdout:
Printed<Long, TsdbObject> printed = Printed.toSysOut();
kstream.print(printed);

KGroupedStream<Long, TsdbObject> kstream_grouped_by_key = kstream.groupByKey(Serialized.with(Serdes.Long(), TsdbObject.getSerde()));
KTable<Long, TsdbObject> summation =
    kstream_grouped_by_key.reduce((tsdb_object1, tsdb_object2) -> {
        System.out.println("reducer: Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        return tsdb_object1;
    });
```

I figured that the first print statement would print out messages with three different
thread id's, and that's what happened.   However, I figured that the second print
statement, being issued in the middle of an aggregation (reducer) operation, would
print out messages listing only one thread id, under the assumption that the reduction
would NOT be multithreaded.   This turned out not to be true:  the second print 
produced messages listing three different thread id's.

Can someone please explain briefly how the aggregation (reducer) is running in
three different threads?   Are they running in parallel?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the aggregation is execute with 3 threads as well, and each thread does the aggregation for about 1/3 of all keys.

Why would you assume that the aggregation is not multithreaded? Note, that it's an aggregation **per key**, thus the result for each key is independent of the result of all others keys. This allows to parallelize the computation.

Comment: I assumed that the data were still divided by original partition for the aggregation, and so there would have to be a serial step to "aggregate the partial aggregations".   It sounds like the groupBy effectively re-partitions the data according to the groupBy key.

Comment: For your case, it does not repartition -- it's three threads overall, and each thread is executing the "whole pipeline" of `mapValue` and the aggregation -- it should be the same thread-ids in both of your print statements.